# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'answers.question_id' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to make a relation
Question `hasMany` Answer

Question.php

```
public function answers()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Answer::class);    
}
```

then displaying Answers for a Question in show.blade.php like:

```
@foreach($question->answers as $answer) 
    {{$answer->ans}} //ans is the answers body from database
@endforeach
```

[image: Answers table in database]

Getting this error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'answers.question_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `answers` where `answers`.`question_id` = 5 and `answers`.`question_id` is not null) (View: C:\Users\harsh\sa1\resources\views\questions\show.blade.php)

Comment: please post your migrations as well

Comment: And how does your answers table look like?

Comment: @kuh-chan Added that.

Comment: `question_id` != `q_id` - you need to be consistent with your naming of columns, otherwise specify it explicitly in `hasMany()`. Easier to just rename `q_id` to `question_id`.

Comment: query say's question_id but your table has column q_id just change that

Comment: either change filed name q_id to question_id in database or specifie field name q_id in relationship

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the laravel model look for the question_id by default when you use a relation. instead you have to mention explicitly. 
Change your relation in model file like this below,

```
  public function answers()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Answer::class, 'q_id', 'id');     
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code to

```php
public function answers()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Answer::class,'q_id','id');    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating `Answer::class` directly to your model class which can be this:

```
public function answers()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Answer', 'q_id', 'id');    
}
```

or this:

```
public function answers()
    {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Answer', 'q_id', 'id');    
    }
```

or wherever you have created your model.
And add the `foreign key` and `local key` constraints which in your case must be `q_id` and `id` where id is the question id (primary key).